# Why can any open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{Q}^\infty$ be written as disjoint union of basic clopen subsets?

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation, rational-numbers, product-space

**Edit:** I asked the same question on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424351/why-can-any-open-subset-u-of-mathbbq-infty-be-written-as-disjoint-union), but I don´t completely understand the answer I got (even if I believe it is great.) Therefore I rephrased the answer here and will appreciate if someone posts another proof or helps explain the proof here).

I am reading Engelen´s paper and have trouble with this proof of Lemma 2.1 (a) (link is below).

> It is easily seen that any non-empty open subspace $U$ of $\mathbb{Q}^\infty$ can be
> written as an infinite disjoint union of non-empty basic clopen
> subsets; hence, $U = \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{Q}^\infty \simeq \mathbb{Q}^\infty$.

In particular, I don't see how the $U$ can be written as the said disjoint union and how that implies that $U \simeq \mathbb{Q}^\infty$

Can anyone please help with this or provide any reading source? I would be really grateful.

Definitions:
$\mathbb{Q}^\infty$ is defined as a set of all rational sequences, endowed with the standard product topology.

Source: Engelen - [Countable Product of zero-dimensional absolute $F_{\sigma \delta}$ spaces](https://ur.booksc.me/book/8624681/d91b4b), Lemma 2.1 (a).

Comment: Sorry about that, the set $B_x=\{x\hat{}s; s\in\mathbb Q^\infty\}$ that I described there isn't actually clopen. (It would be if we worked with the discrete topology on $\mathbb Q$, but we have the usual topology.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak I see... I think $\mathcal B=\left\{(x,y)\cap\Bbb Q\,\middle|\,x,y\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q\wedge x<y\right\}$ could be a basis (consisting of clopen sets)  for $\mathbb{Q}$ with the usual topology and this could help create the basis for $\mathbb{Q}^\infty$ ... But I am still not sure, how to proceed.

Comment: This would be a clopen basis for $\mathbb Q$. Probably it would be more useful to take a *countable* clopen basis of $\mathbb Q$ which additionally has a property that any two sets in $\mathcal B$ are either disjoint or comparable. (Such basis can be obtained, for example, from taking open intervals of the form $(\sqrt2+\frac{k}{2^n},\sqrt2+\frac{k+1}{2^n})$ and intersecting them with $\mathbb Q$.) But even after that, I am not exactly sure how to make a similar argument as before (i.e., how to get a basis for the product topology which elements are either disjoint or comparable).

Comment: It the meantime, somebody [posted an answer on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/424351). Let us hope that one will lead in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer in MO was written hastily, here is the same proof but in more detail (and better notation):

First, for each sequence $s=(S_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of clopen sets of $\mathbb{Q}$, let $A_s$ be the subset $\prod_{n\in\mathbb{N}} S_n$ of $\mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}$. Note that if $S_n=\mathbb{Q}$ for all $n$ except finitely many, then $A_s$ is clopen. I will call sets of this form "basic clopens". As $\mathbb{Q}$ has a basis formed by clopen sets (e.g. intervals with irrational ends), basic clopens form a basis for the topology of $\mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}$.

Also note that nonempty basic clopens are homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}$. This is a consequence of the fact that any nonempty clopen of $\mathbb{Q}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$ by [Sierpinski's Theorem](https://math.wvu.edu/%7Ekciesiel/Other/ElectronicReprints/141.SierpinskiThmOnQReprint.pdf).

For any two basic clopens $A_s$ and $A_t$, the clopen $A_s\cap A_t$ is given by $A_r$, where $r=(R_n)_n$ is given by $R_n=S_n\cap T_n$. So it is also a basic clopen.

**Lemma:** The complement of any basic clopen $A_s$ is a finite union of basic clopens.

Proof: For each sequence $\xi$ of elements of $\{-1,1\}$, consider the clopen $A_{s_\xi}$, where $s_\xi$ is the sequence given by $S_n$ if $\xi_n=1$ or $\mathbb{Q}\setminus S_n$ if $\xi_n=-1$. Note that $A_{s,\xi}$ is empty for all $\xi$ except finitely many, and if for some $\xi$ we have that $A_{s,\xi}$ is nonempty, then it is clopen. Moreover, the sets $\{A_{s_\xi}\}_{\xi\in\{-1,1\}^\mathbb{N}}$ are pairwise disjoint and their union is all $\mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}$. So the complement of $A_s=A_{s_{(1,1,1,\dots)}}$ is just the union of the rest of clopens $A_{s,\xi}$, with $\xi\neq(1,1,1,\dots)$, which are nonempty. $\square$

**Corollary:** If $A_1,\dots,A_n$ are basic clopens, then $A_n\setminus\bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1}A_i$ is a finite union of basic clopens.

Proof: $A_n\setminus\bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1}A_i=\bigcap_{i=1}^{n-1}(A_n\setminus A_i)$. Each set $A_n-A_i$ is a finite union of basic clopens, because it is $A_n\cap(\mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}\setminus A_i)$. So their intersection is also a finite union of basic clopens.$\square$

Now consider any open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}$. As $\mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}$ is second countable and basic clopens form a basis for its topology, we can express $U=\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}U_n$, where the $U_n$ are all basic clopens. Letting $V_n=U_n\setminus\bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1}U_i$, we also have $U=\cup_n V_n$. The $V_n$ are pairwise disjoint, and each one is a finite union of disjoint clopens. So we have obtained a form to express $U$ as a union of disjoint clopens.

We also want infinitely many of the clopens to be non-empty: for that, it is enough to have infinitely many non empty $V_n$: this can be achieved by choosing the cover $U_n$ of $U$ in such a way that no finite union of the $U_n$ cover $U$.

To obtain a cover of $U$ by clopens such that no finitely many of them cover $U$, we can do the following: let $\pi_m:\mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Q}$ be the m$^\text{th}$ projection of the product $\mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}$ onto its factors. As $U$ is open, we have $\pi_m(U)=\mathbb{Q}$ for some $m\in\mathbb{N}$. Now take an arbitrary open cover $U_n$ of $U$ and let $U_{n,k}=U_n\cap\pi_m^{-1}((-k\pi,k\pi))$. The cover $(U_{n,k})_{n,k}$ of $U$ satisfies what we want because for any union $X$ of finitely many of the $U_{n,k}$, $\pi_m(X)$ is bounded, so $X\neq U$.

So, for any open set $U$ of $\mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}$, we have obtained $U$ as an infinite union of disjoint basic clopens, which in turn are homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}$. So, $U$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}$. Note that this also aplies to the open set $U'=\mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}$. So $\mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}$ is also homeomorphic to $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}$, thus $U$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}$.

**Note:** A similar, easier proof works to show that any open subset of the Cantor set $\mathcal{C}\subseteq[0,1]$ which is not compact is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{N}\times\mathcal{C}$: we can take a base of clopen sets of the Cantor set (which are homeomorphic to $\mathcal{C}$ by [Brouwer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_space#Characterization)). Then we can express any open subset $U$ of $\mathcal{C}$ as a union of a sequence $A_n$ of these clopen sets. Letting $B_n=A_n\setminus\bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1}A_i$, $B_n$ are clopen so they are either empty or homeomorphic to $\mathcal{C}$. Moreover, as $U=\bigcup_nB_n$ is not compact, infinitely many of the $B_n$ have to be non empty. So $U\simeq\mathbb{N}\times\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate that you explained this. Btw I noticed you sometimes denote $\mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}$ and sometimes $\mathbb{Q}^\infty$, but this may be a detail. I am really grateful and will give you a bounty for this question.

Comment: Yeah I edited that. I usually prefer to write $\mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}$; $\mathbb{Q}^\infty$ sounds to me like it should represent the subset of $\mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}$ formed by sequences with finitely many non zero elements. But yes, it's just notation

Answer (score 0):

This is my own attempt to answer this question. I am using answer by Saúl RM on [stackoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424351/why-can-any-open-subset-u-of-mathbbq-infty-be-written-as-disjoint-union), where I posted the same question, so credits go to them. Please correct me if I am wrong in anything, thank you.

---

**(1)** Goal of the proof is to see that $U \simeq \mathbb{Q}^\omega$ where $U$ is nonempty and open.

First, observe that we can express any such $U$ as countable union of basic clopen subsets $(A_n)$ where for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $A_n =\{(q_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}};i_{n,k}<q_k<j_{n,k} \text{ for $k=1,\dots,n$}\}$, where $i_{n,k}$ and $j_{n,k}$ are irrational numbers.

Each such $A_n$ is therefore a sequence of rational numbers $q_k$ located between pairs of irrational numbers $i_{n,k}, j_{n,k}$, such that for the fixed $n$, we have one pair of such numbers for each $k \leq n$. In total, this will give us $n$ pairs of irrational numbers and hence $n$ sequences of rationals (one between each pair).

Important is that some $A_n$ can be empty, only finitely many $A_n$ may be nonempty. $U$ can be always written as their union, but we can have a situation like $U = A_1$.

**(2)** Now, we need to express $A_n\setminus\bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1}A_i$ as a finite union of disjoint basic clopens. **Here, I don´t really understand why we can do that.**

**(3)** To do the abovesaid, we can work in $\mathbb{Q}^n$ instead of $\mathbb{Q}^\omega$ due to the construction of the sets $A_n$. This **I also don´t really understand.**

**(4)** Writing $\mathbb{Q}^n=\mathbb{Q}_1\times\dots\times\mathbb{Q}_n$, notice that for each $k\leq n$, the irrationals $i_{1,k},\dots,i_{n,k},j_{1,k},\dots,j_{n,k}$ give a partition of $\mathbb{Q}_k$ into finitely many clopen subsets. Taking a product of these partitions, we obtain a partition of $\mathbb{Q}^n$ into disjoint clopens such that any of the $A_i$, with $i\leq n$, is a finite union of these clopens. So $A_n\setminus\bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1}A_i$ is also a finite union of the clopens.

**(5)** If we pick the $A_n$ so that no finite union of them covers $U$, we also get infinitely many non empty clopens. **I also don´t understand this step.**

**(6)**
This implies that $U\equiv\mathbb{Q}^\infty$ because any basic clopen set like the ones above is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}^\infty$, which can be deduced using that any clopen subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$ by [Sierpinski's theorem](https://math.wvu.edu/%7Ekciesiel/Other/ElectronicReprints/141.SierpinskiThmOnQReprint.pdf).